# GitHub Pages Failed to load resource:

Tags: javascript, d3.js, github-pages

I created a website to display different production data and want to make it accessible through GitHub pages, but I get 2 errors on every page that is reading data from a .json file. I am also using d3. These my errors:

1. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
2. ```
   Uncaught (in promise) Error: 404 
    at Zo (d3.min.js:2)
   Zo @ d3.min.js:2
   Promise.then (async)
   createDropdownOptions @ curves.js:8
   (anonymous) @ curves.js:21
   ```

I think the issue is related to the .json format, but unsure of how to fix it. The webpage deploys perfectly on my local server.

Here is my GitHub Pages: (The issue is with the "TODAY'S IMPORT" & "SITES" tabs, "HAWKWOOD" tab seems to be displaying because it isn't pulling in any data)
https://gabrielavalos.github.io/HAWKWOOD/

And here is the repo:
https://github.com/gabrielavalos/HAWKWOOD

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You need a relative link: `d3.json('./static/todaysImport.json').then((data) => {`. Pay attention to that dot before `/static`.

Comment: This solved it! Thank you so much. Can you explain what exactly the "." does? How does that make it a relative link?

Comment: Sure, MDN is a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL. Go to the section *"absolute URL versus relative URL"*.